# recursive sequential search does not return value

Tags: python, recursion

I am implementing a recursive sequential search on Python like this:

```
def search(list1,n,pos):
    if n==list1[0]:
        return pos
    else:
        if list1==[]:
            return -1
        else:
            pos=pos+1
            list1.pop(0)
            return search(list1,n,pos)

def searchCall(n):
    anylist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    pos=0
    search(anylist,n,pos)

def main():
    i=searchCall(8)
    print i

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

so what I do is to try to find the element n on the list, and in each recursive call I pop out the first element of the list, calling the search again with the remaining list. The problem is that when I put this:

```
if n==list1[0]:
        print pos
```

it prints the position where the element is found, but when I changed with:

```
return pos
```

it prints None

also when the element is not found it should return -1, but instead displays this error message:

```
if n==list1[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

any help?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an element is not found, you have popped every item in the list, so its length is 0. That means that you should check for that condition at the beginning:

```
def search(list1,n,pos):
    if list1==[]:
        return -1

    if n==list1[0]:
        return pos
    else:
        pos=pos+1
        list1.pop(0)
        return search(list1,n,pos)

def searchCall(n):
    anylist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    pos=0
    print search(anylist,n,pos)
```

**EDIT**: As Innox said, you are good only as long as you call `searchCall`, because it instantiates a new list every time, but `search` consumes your haystack, so it's a one time search.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful.

First, your function works as expected when the value is there. Just did list1 = [1,2,3,4,5] and called search(list1,3,0) and got 2 as answer.

One issue with your implementation is that it pops values of the list. So if you try to reuse the list, it will be incomplete. After the search call, list1 is [3,4,5].

Second. Your implementation is wrong when the value is not in the list. Basically you should perform the list1 == [] check (or len(list1) == 0) before n == list[0].

Answer (score 2):

It is because you don't return the value of `search(anylist,n,pos)`
That's why it prints only None. Because the function itself did not return anything and therefore when you wanted to print the result, it is None.
When you return the result of `search` then you can print the result of `searchCall` function.

You have to change the function to:

```
def searchCall(n):
    anylist=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    pos=0
    return search(anylist,n,pos)
```

And you get the exception because you first ask for the first item of the list which does not exist in the case when the list is empty.

So I suggest this modification to the `search` function

```
def search(list1,n,pos):
    if list1==[]:
        return -1
    elif n==list1[0]:
        return pos;
    else:
        pos=pos+1
        list1.pop(0)
        b= search(list1,n,pos)
        return b;
```

You first verify whether the list is empty and then you continue.

**EDIT:**

Just to make it complete ... 
With this `main` function it prints **-1**

```
def main():
    print searchCall(15);
```

and this `main` function prints **3**

```
def main():
    print searchCall(4);
```